# Flask app in docker is not loading the updated html

Tags: html, docker, flask, caching, gunicorn

I have containerized my flask app into a docker image. The application adds new content to an existing html (rendered in flask app) based on a POST response. While the new contents of html are displayed correctly on my local, app ran from docker still displays the old content.  I have put in checks to confirm that POST request is successfully sent as well as to confirm that new contents are being added. Upon restart though, the docker container displays the contents of html correctly upon restarting the docker container.

I am suspecting that the container is caching html files. Is there a setting while building the docker to not cache the contents of html?

```
#start by pulling the python image
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

#copy the requirements file into the image
COPY ./requirements.txt/app/requirements.txt

#switch working directory
WORKDIR /app

#install the dependencies and packages in the requirements file
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#copy every content from the local file to the image
COPY ./app

CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 driver:app
```

Comment: Docker on its own doesn't "know about" HTTP in any useful way, and won't change the caching behavior of your application.  This is a pretty generic Dockerfile for a Python application; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] with enough details to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the code below

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    app.jinja_env.cache = {}
```

and calling it inside main() like below solves the issue

```
app.before_request(before_request)
```